# Apache Tika strange whitespace symbols

Tags: whitespace, apache-tika

I am trying to extract the text from sample pdf located [here](https://www.soundczech.cz/temp/lorem-ipsum.pdf) by using Apache Tika.

Using the GUI of Apache Tike (run from console: `java -jar tika-app-1.22.jar`) seems to produce plain text pretty well. The text looks like this:
[image: apache tika gui]

The issue when I try to extract the text by running the following command:

```
java -jar tika-app-1.22.jar --text lorem-ipsum.pdf
```

This produces text that has the `á` character everywhere whitespace is expected:
[image: apache tika console]

Any help configuring the command to produce normal whitespaces is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Looks fine for me on Ubuntu. Could it be a powershell issue? If you run it from a regular windows command prompt, is it better? If you pipe the output into a text file and open that, does that look fine?

Comment: Interesting. Piping to a text file from powershell produces the same result as the screenshot. Running the command from comand prompt, produces the same result as on the screenshot. BUT, piping from command prompt seems to produce clean text file. Could it be encoding issue?

Comment: Could be! Try passing the `--encoding=` flag, with something sensible like `UTF-8`, and see if that solves it for you? (See `--help` for details of all the supported options)

Comment: Piping to text file from powershell with --encoding=Unicode seems to output correctly (although if not piped, the result in powershell again seems weird). Thanks for the hint.